# @Value annotation of Springboot can't find JKS file location for Kafka Producer Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using a Kafka Producer with SSL authentication and setting `kafka.ssl.keystore.location = C:\\Users\\Documnets\\filelocation.jks`. There is another bean which needs to be started prior to my producer, and it uses the producer 
So, I am auto-wiring this Producer with its config in that initializing bean.

Somehow, `@Value(${kafka.ssl.keystore.location})`, can't be resolved. I get Placeholder couldn't be resolved error.

Answer (score 0):

It's `spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location`. But, you should never, never, invoke a producer from an initialization method; it's too early. Implement `SmartLifecycle` instead and put your code in the `start()` method.

Set the `phase` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` so it is started very early.

Comment: `>The send method of Producer is called in my initialising bean itself .` I will repeat - sending to a producer during bean initialization is too early.

Comment: Thanks for answering Gary !  That solved. I now deployed my code to Kubernetes and created a secret for jks under volume mount /etc/secrets/keystore. I am trying accessing jks in my code setting ssl.keystore.location to file:///etc/secrets/keystore/ssl.jks. I get no file found exception now :(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812478/ssl-keystore-location-cant-find-jks-file-in-my-kubernetes-secrets-mount/61820030#61820030