# SSL.keystore.location can't find JKS file in my Kubernetes secrets mount

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, spring-kafka, kubernetes-secrets

I have created a secret for my JKS file under volume mount /etc/secrets/keystore.
I am accessing my JKS file path as an environment variable where ssl.keystore.location gets resolved as file:///etc/secrets/keystore/ssl.jks. But I get exception from SSL engine builder that modification time of keystore couldn't be found and java.nio.file.NoSuchFile Exception file:/etc/secrets/keystore/ssl.jks

Comment: /etc/secrets/keystore/SSL.jks or /etc/secrets/keystore/ssl.jks ?! Uppercase problem ?

Comment: Nope , Sorry I didn't copy . So, while typing didn't care about case. It's not about case sensitivity , edited.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `file://`. The keystore is opened by the Kafka client, not Spring.

Kafka knows nothing about Spring's `Resource` abstraction; you need to provide just the path to the file (relative or absolute).